# Share only link from Safari to Mail

Tags: safari, mail.app, sharing

When a friend uses the Share button in Safari to send me a link by email, the email I receive is a huge (and very buggy!) reconstruction of the Webpage including pictures and everything.

How can I reconfigure macOS to only share a single line with the link itself and nothing more?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether it's possible... but the workaround is so simple it's easier than reaching over to the Share button.

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd>  which moves focus to the address bar.
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  to copy the address.
- Switch to Mail
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  for new mail.
- fill in address & title
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  to paste the URL

Comment: That's exactly what I told my friend :) But for a non-tech user, the Share button would be more intuitive and involve fewer clicks.

Comment: For sure - wait to see if someone knows a true answer to your question. Personally, I find the 'workaround' easier & quicker than the Share button :)